# Is it possible to move "Edit" and "Delete" buttons to the front in CRUD?

Tags: atk4

I created a model with ~30 columns, so every time I need to edit or delete something in CRUD, I have to scroll to the rightmost to find the edit or delete button.  Is it possible to move them to the first 2 columns in the grid?

Also, it seems the CRUD class is derived from "View" rather than "Grid", so the addPaginator() function does not work here.  Is there any way I can separate the data into different pages in CRUD? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CRUD is a container for both Grid and Form. Depending on how the page is called, it will initialize a proper sub-element. To do something with grid, such as adding pagination, you need this:

```
if($crud->grid)$crud->grid->addPaginatior();
```

Also if you are looking to re-order columns, then this is what you need to do:

```
if($crud->grid)$crud->grid->addOrder()
    ->move('edit','first')
    ->move('delete','after','edit')
    ->now();
```

Comment: actually you can divert the move by replacing `now()` with `onHook($this->api,'pre-render')`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit button moves just as Romaninsh said, but I'n not able to move the delete button...

Comment: this is by design.. the `delete` button is immovable on grids and will always stay at the last column because it is controlled by an internal function `init_delete` that adds a `post-init` hook which calls a second function named `_move_delete` which does the actual moving of the button..